# Determine which copy constructors is called in C++ code

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, operator-overloading

I have written a simple C++ class example with 1 non-param constructor, 1 param constructor, 2 copy constructors, 1 assignment operator and 1 plus operator.

```
class Complex {
protected:
    float real, img;
public:
    Complex () : real(0), img(0) {
        cout << "Default constructor\n";
    }

    Complex (float a, float b) {
        cout << "Param constructor" << a << " " << b << endl;
        real = a;
        img = b;
    }

    // 2 copy constructors
    Complex( const Complex& other ) {
        cout << "1st copy constructor " << other.real << " " << other.img << endl;
        real = other.real;
        img = other.img;
    }

    Complex( Complex& other ) {
        cout << "2nd copy constructor " << other.real << " " << other.img << endl;
        real = other.real;
        img = other.img;
    }

    // assignment overloading operator
    void operator= (const Complex& other) {
        cout << "assignment operator " << other.real << " " << other.img << endl;
        real = other.real;
        img = other.img;
    }

    // plus overloading operator
    Complex operator+ (const Complex& other) {
        cout << "plus operator " << other.real << " " << other.img << endl;
        float a = real + other.real;
        float b = img + other.img;
        return Complex(a, b);
    }

    float getReal () {
        return real;
    }

    float getImg () {
        return img;
    }
};
```

I used this class in main exactly like this:

```
int main() {
    Complex a(1,5);
    Complex b(5,7);
    Complex c = a+b; // Statement 1
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Result is printed as:

```
Param constructor 1 5
Param constructor 5 7
plus operator 5 7
Param constructor 6 12
```

I think a copy constructor must be used in Statement 1, but I dont really know which one is called.
Please tell me which one, and why?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Should be `const` version of copy constructor, you can always put debug prints in the constructor bodies to check it yourself.

Comment: @iammilind if ctor is elided, the print out statements are elided too, which is allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is eliding the call (actually, *two* calls) to the copy constructor. This is allowed (but not mandated!) per paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard even if the constructor or destructor have side effects:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, **even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects**. [..]
>   This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>
> [...]
>
> — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

If the compiler did not elide the calls to the copy constructor, then the first one would be picked twice, i.e. the one with the following signature:

```
Complex( const Complex& other )
```

The reason is that:

- The value returned by `operator +` is copy-initialized from a temporary (`Complex(a, b)`), and only lvalue references to `const` can bind to temporaries. Things would be different if `operator +` were written like so:

  ```
  Complex operator+ (const Complex& other) {
      // ...
      Complex c(a, b);
      return c;
  }
  ```

  In this case, the second copy constructor would be called, since `c` is not `const`-qualified and is an lvalue, so it can be bound to an lvalue reference to non-`const`;
- Object `c` in `main()` is being copy-constructed from an rvalue (the value returned by `operator +` is also a temporary). This is true no matter how `operator +` returns its `Complex` object, as long as it returns it by value. Therefore, the first copy constructor will be picked whenever copy elision is not performed.

If you are using GCC and want to verify this behavior, try setting the `-fno-elide-constructors` compilation flag (Clang supports it too, but version 3.2 had a bug and I don't know whether it was fixed).